# Converting strings of tuples within list of lists to list items in Python

Tags: python, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

List `l` contains items consisting of two types of lists, the first being acceptable lists consisting of strings and the second consisting of strings of tuples containing strings. All lists of the second type are of the same length - 2. I want to convert all lists of the second type to the same convention as the first type, as demonstrated below (`l2` is the updated list).

Edit: I should clarify that the actual list I am dealing with as far more than two items, so I need a loop function to accommodate this.

```
l = [["('N', '', 'SHOWERS', '', 'RD', '11734', '11734', '', '')", "('61060', '61060')"], ['', '', 'NORA', '', 'RD', '10301', '10999', '10400', '10998', '61089', '61089']]

l2 = [['N', '', 'SHOWERS', '', 'RD', '11734', '11734', '', '', '61060', '61060'], ['', '', 'NORA', '', 'RD', '10301', '10999', '10400', '10998', '61089', '61089']]
```

The following only gets me so far:

```
from csv import reader
from cStringIO import StringIO

l2 = []

for i in l:
    if len(i) == 2:
        filestr = StringIO(i[0] + i[1])
        csv_reader = reader(filestr, quotechar="'")
        for t in csv_reader:
            l2.append(t)
    else:
        l2.append(i)
```

Comment: You have two identifiers called `i` in this code. Can you give them more meaningful names so that they don't clash? Also, your indentation is off and needs to be fixed.

Comment: I distinguished the identifiers for clarity, but I'm not aware of any indentation issues. Can you point out where that exists?

Comment: The line underneath `for t in csv_reader:` needs to be indented further. I've also just spotted this: `if len(i) is 2:`. You should check for *equality*, not *identity*.

Comment: @user1185790: You still have `i = i[0] + i[1]`, which means that you are using `i` for two different purposes. It won't break anything in this case, but it's confusing. Since you only use the value once, you may as well just write `file = StringIO(i[0] + i[1])`.

Comment: One last nitpick: `file` is a Python built-in. Renaming that to something else (`fake_file`) would be a good idea. In fact, I think if you fix all of my little nitpicks, your code may actually work!

Comment: Haha. All valid points, Johnsyweb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a csv problem, since you don't have a csv. (In fact you confused me for some time because I was trying to imagine what the csv file looked like!)

1. Establish a "test" of whether a list needs normalization (`is_tuple_string_row` function below).
2. Use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely convert the string-of-tuple into an actual tuple.
3. Use [`chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to combine all the tuples into a single sequence.

Full code below implemented as the generator `normalized_list()`.

```
l = [["('N', '', 'SHOWERS', '', 'RD', '11734', '11734', '', '')", "('61060', '61060')"], ['', '', 'NORA', '', 'RD', '10301', '10999', '10400', '10998', '61089', '61089']]

l2 = [['N', '', 'SHOWERS', '', 'RD', '11734', '11734', '', '', '61060', '61060'], ['', '', 'NORA', '', 'RD', '10301', '10999', '10400', '10998', '61089', '61089']]

import ast
from itertools import imap, chain


def is_tuple_string_row(L):
    """Return whether list L is a list of strings containing tuples"""
    return len(L)==2 and all(s.startswith("('") and s.endswith("')") for s in L)


def normalized_list(L):
    """Yield lists in sequence L as lists of strings

    Normalizes a list of strings of tuples down to a simple list of strings
    """
    for item in L:
        if is_tuple_string_row(item):
            yield list(chain.from_iterable(imap(ast.literal_eval, item)))
        else:
            yield item


# You can iterate efficiently
for item in normalized_list(l):
    print item

# or you can put the whole thing to a single new list
aslist = list(normalized_list(l))

# verify results
assert aslist == l2
```

Comment: Wow, Francis, thanks for this! It worked for `l`, now I'll have to test this on a full list containing more than just two items.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ast:

```
>>> import ast
>>> l = [["('N', '', 'SHOWERS', '', 'RD', '11734', '11734', '', '')", "('61060', '61060')"], ['', '', 'NORA', '', 'RD', '10301', '10999', '10400', '10998', '61089', '61089']]
>>> l2=[e for e in ast.literal_eval(l[0][0])]
>>> l2+=[e for e in ast.literal_eval(l[0][1])]
>>> l2=[l2]
>>> l2.append(l[1])

>>> l2
[['N', '', 'SHOWERS', '', 'RD', '11734', '11734', '', '', '61060', '61060'], ['', '', 'NORA', '', 'RD', '10301', '10999', '10400', '10998', '61089', '61089']]
```

As you may know, `eval` has some real security issues. `ast` is quite safe since it can only produce Python base data structures.

Comment: If my list `l` is greater than two items, is there an efficient way to apply `ast.literal_eval` through a loop process?

Answer (score 1):

If, *and only if*, you trust the input, you can eval it:

```
l2 = eval(l[0][0])
```

I don't fully understand the structure of the entire input, so I can't help you with looping over all of it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. The actual input list is more than two items, so I need a loop for this problem.

Comment: You can use `ast.literal_eval` and avoid security issues.

Comment: @user1185790: I understand, but eval only works on the sub-items in the first item. I suppose the fact that the first item has exactly two sub-items is relevant, but you'll have to work through the details yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend working with Lists instead of Tuples, and then indexing the lists / sublists / and sublists of list if necessary to achieve what you want.

Another Idea would be to make a Class of the structure that you want.  Put methods that slice the list.  It appears that you want the first 9 items in a tuple, and the last two in a separate tuple.  This would be a good way to separate them out as well.